# All kinds of WWW issues in Unity Engine

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

since I started logging all database connection issues by sending an email from the player's device to myself, about 1-2% of my players got all sorts of errors. I googled them one by one, but most of the time, the solution didn't really pertrain in my case.

I get e.g.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host <url here>: No address associated with hostname
```

quite often. Forums say, that the reason for that is the lack of internet. So this can't be true, because I'm recieving an email, so the player definitely has internet. Could it be, that the email sending is queued up until internet is available again? The `InternetReachability` is `ReachableViaLocalAreaNetwork` most of the time, but sometimes also `ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork` sometimes. My next guess would be, that the user has wifi, but the router currently has no internet - then the sending gets queued up and once the router has email again, the mail is being sent. This would analogeously be the case for the carrier datanetwork, where it's turned `on` on the phone, but currently there's no internet connection and the mail get's queued up.

Other `www` errors I recieve are

```
500: Internal Server Error
408: Request Timeout
503: Service Unavailable
```

from which I would think that the target website is down, but my server host told me, it's 100% online.

I also get

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: 15
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

which I can't explain at all.

There's also

```
403: Forbidden
```

sometimes, which I could possibly understand, if in certain countries the access to some domains is restricted. Is that the reason for it?

And last, but not least

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to <url here>/<ip here> (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

I think these issues might have different causes, because otherwise it would be the same issue all the time. Is there a nice solution to this, or do I have wo write all sorts of exceptions for these cases and hope that not too many players are experiencing the issues?

Comment: On the device, are you able to reach the destination in a browser? Are you personally able to navigate to the destination from another device? Perhaps there's a firewall setting on port 80. For the `500` error, look in your error log.

Comment: Yes, thousands of players and I are able to do the connection. It must be like 1-2% of players who get these issues.